# Promise extending into more promises results in unpredictable data format (and unreadable code)

Tags: javascript, stack, promise

I'm trying to rewrite some 'old' code using promises. Currently the code uses its own stack, which is accessible from all the callbacks and sometimes new items are added to the stack, until it's empty, and then the final callback runs, with a pretty format for all the collected data (also accessible in all the callbacks).

The main point here being: `stack` and `data` are accessible from all the callbacks, so every callback can add to `data` with `push`. The end result is always a 1D aray.

1. The process always starts with `Promise.all([a, b])`
2. `a` adds to `data` and that's it
3. `b` might add to `data` and that's it, **but** more likely it spawns more promises
4. these promises add to `data` and/or spawn more promises
5. etc, in theory inifinitely, but it's usually only 1-3 levels deep

For every new spawn in `b`, the previous result is necessary, so I can't start them all together with `a` and `b`.

I've made a simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/6r5smkz5/ (check console and click on blank body to run again)

- Sometimes `b` returns a scalar (data immediately)
- Sometimes it returns the data from more spawns (array)
- And those spawns might also return data from more spawns (more arrays!)

So the data can look like:

- `[a, b]`
- `[a, [b, b]]`
- `[a, [b, [c, c, c], [c, c]]]` (not in the demo, only 2 levels)

etc

And it should always look like:

- `[a, b, c, c, c, c, c]` (1D, any number of elements)

In every `then(callback)` I only have the results from that `P.all`, never ALL of it, until the very last done, where the format can be anything.

This is the processor:

```js
console.time('ALL LOADED');
Promise.all([local(), sync()])
.then(function(data) {
    // data[0] (from a) is always scalar
    // data[1] (from 1 or more b's) might be Array
    if (data[1] instanceof Array) {
        data[1].unshift(data[0]);
        return data[1];
    }
    return data;
})
.then(function(data) {
    console.log('DONE', data);
    console.timeEnd('ALL LOADED');
    console.log('');
});
```

As you can see, the first `then(callback)` formats the data to that 1D array I need. This one is simple, but with more levels, it's bigger.

My question mainly: is this the right method? Isn't there an 'after every `then(callback)`' to keep formatting the data easily? Or even better: easier access to the global `data`, like in my current set-up.

Or add to the first `P.all` stack while it's still running? That would be the best. Only 1 `then(callback)` with one `data`, but with variable size.

Promises are cool, but complicated stuff is still complicated, or even more so.

Comment: I'd use return values instead of a global object to communicate what objects do and what they return. This approach sounds very hard to synchronize. Also, I'm not sure why you're using a nested array and not, for example, a tree on which you can implement a simpler iterator.

Comment: How would I use the tree + iterator? Example plz? (The stack and data in my current solution aren't completely global, but their scope is outside all the callbacks.)

Comment: Sounds like you want a recursive function.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but how would I add to `data` and pass around the promises? Isn't a stack like I have now a better, more readable solution?

Comment: Usually I find recursion easier to understand than a stack :-) Your tasks seem to operate only on the head of the stack anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. So a global-ish `data` that's filled recursively? No promises? How do I know everyone's done? Async recursion...

Comment: No global-ish data, just use the promises return values. Use `Promise.all` for aggregation

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't tried using promises with recursion before, so I messed around with it a little bit.  I'm not sure if this will be helpful for you, but it was fun for me.

I'm still working on not using the globalData variable as the accumulator, but it gets kind of weird passing the accumulator around in the promises, and I'm not sure why yet.

```
var prom = require('bluebird'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    globalData = []

/**
 * return a number 1/2 of the time, array rest of the time
 */
function asyncSometimesArrayDataSource() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return prom.resolve(2);
    } else {
        return prom.resolve([1, 2]);
    }
};


function asyncAlwaysIntDataSource() {
    return prom.resolve(2);
}


function recursivePromises(arr) {
    return prom.all(asyncSometimesArrayDataSource()
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data instanceof Array) {
                return prom.all(data.map(function (val) {

                    globalData.push(val)
                    return recursivePromises();
                }));
            } else {
                globalData.push(data);
                return globalData;
            }
        }));

}

asyncAlwaysIntDataSource()
    .then(function (easyData) {
        return recursivePromises()
            .then(function () {
                return globalData;
            });
    })
    .then(function (finaldata) {
        console.log('final data', finaldata);
    });
```

Here is an improved version of the previous attempt, with no external accumulation array.

```
var prom = require('bluebird'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    // count is used to verify that the final array is the correct length
    count = 0;


/**
 * return a number 1/2 of the time, array rest of the time
 */
function asyncSometimesArrayDataSource() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return prom.resolve(2);
    } else {
        return prom.resolve([4, 5]);
    }
}


function asyncAlwaysIntDataSource() {
    count++;
    return prom.resolve(2);
}



function recursivePromises(arr) {
    return asyncSometimesArrayDataSource()
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data instanceof Array) {
                return prom.map(data, function (val) {
                    count++;
                    return recursivePromises([val]);
                }).then(function (mapdata) {
                    return arr.concat(mapdata);
                });
            } else {
                count++;
                arr.push(data);
                return arr;
            }
        });
}

asyncAlwaysIntDataSource()
    .then(function (easyData) {
        return recursivePromises([easyData])
    })
    .then(function (finaldata) {
        console.log('final data', _.flatten(finaldata), count, _.flatten(finaldata).length);
    });
```

Comment: `recursivePromises()` is very strange. You're not using `arr` and did you intend to pass 1 promise (incl `.then`) into `prom.all()`? I don't like the `globalData` very much =) I do like how it's returned by the second-to-last `then()` so it's passed to the last `then()` as its data/value argument =) Very smooth.

Comment: I think my stack + recursion is more readable (and all global-ish). If only a promise executor could append to the list of promises in `all()`... Start with 2, have it extended, 1 result when they're all done. Ah, if only.

Comment: yeah leaving arr in the original answer was a typo.  i'm still not sure if the updated answer is better for you, but i'm happy to have figured out a way to make recursion work with promises a little bit.  the arr.concat(mapdata) part still seems a little awkward, but i'm not sure how to get around that.